# Class Type T - Explained

Tags: scala, slick, typesafe

Can anyone explain too me why I get the following compiler exception while declaring the TableQuery inside my trait.

```
class type required but T found
```

Isn't the T actually a Class type or am I mistaken?

```
trait TableModel[T <: Table[_]] {
  val table: TableQuery[T] = TableQuery[T]    <~~~~~~~~~~ class type required but T found

  def exists(implicit session: Session): Boolean =
    (!MTable.getTables(table.baseTableRow.tableName).list.isEmpty)

  def schemaDescription: MySQLDriver.SchemaDescription = table.ddl

  def create(implicit session: Session): Unit =  schemaDescription.create

  def drop(implicit session: Session): Unit =  schemaDescription.drop
}


object UsersTable extends TableModel[Users] {}
```

Comment: What line are you getting that error on? This usually happens when you try to create an instance of a generic parameter, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591957/class-type-required-but-t-found .

Comment: val table: TableQuery[T] = TableQuery[T]

The Exception is on the following line

Comment: The question you replied with is not exactly the same as my question. While the question you posted tries to create an instance of T, all i want to do is reuse the generic inside another generic class supplied by slick.

Comment: `T` is a type parameter, not a class type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you get this error message is that `TableQuery[T]` in value position is actually `TableQuery.apply[T]` which is a macro that expands into `new TableQuery(new T(_))`. It is not certain from only the type constraint `T <: Table[_]` that `T` is a **non-abstract** class that you can call `new` on (public constructor). The actual error message scalac gives here isn't very precise here but in the right ballpark.

Answer (score 0):

You need define abstract TableQuery reference instead of concrete.

```
trait TableModel[T <: Table[_]] {

   val table: TableQuery[T]

   def exists(implicit session: Session): Boolean =
    (!MTable.getTables(table.baseTableRow.tableName).list.isEmpty)

   def schemaDescription: MySQLDriver.SchemaDescription = table.ddl

   def create(implicit session: Session): Unit = schemaDescription.create

   def drop(implicit session: Session): Unit = schemaDescription.drop
  }

object UsersTable extends TableModel[Users] {
 val table = TableQuery[Users]
 }
```